# GPU on limit on complex drag & drop operation but only without dev tools open

Tags: angular, google-chrome, svg, gpu

I'm dragging a div over a giant svg and my CPU goes wild without dev tools open. The dragging animation is laggy and after a second it highlights the text from the SVG, because the mouse lost track.

But this is only as long as the tools are closed, even if i move them to my second monitor (so the SVG doesn't get smaller leaving the GPU with the same size to render.)

Specs:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
- Chrome @latest (103) (no non-default flags or settings)
- using Angular 9 as frontend
- my SVG is 6k lines long and I set the width / height to 19200 x 10800 with a view box of 1920 x 1080 (for dev reasons... Was easier to manipulate it that way and I also don't understand svg tbh =/ )

I use an `@hostlistener mousemove` in my app.component for the mouseposition (`event.x, event.y`). Then I `next()` a global service subject and `.subscribe` to that in the component which needs to be dragged. I then set the style attributes of my div => `left: event.x; top event.y` while the wrapper has a `position: fixed.` Maybe that's not ideal? But how come it's working fine with the dev tools open?

[image: blue: no dev tools - red: dev tools open]

Comment: report it to [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) and see what they say.

Comment: Since you say there is text highlighting going on, maybe you should try to supress mouse interactions with a `event.preventDefault()` on `mousedown`.